# Generating "resource allocation" report using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to generate a report based on the below two tables:

```
  Name        Start Year    End Year    No. Of Students Fill Order
School-ABC      2000         2004            1             1
School-DEF      2000         2004            2             3    
School-GHI      2000         2004            1             2    

  Name        Start Year    End Year    Joined On
Student-1       2000         2004        01-Jan
Student-2       2000         2004        03-Jan
Student-3       2000         2004        02-Jan
Student-4       2000         2004        15-Jan
```

The expected output is below:

```
  Name        Start Year    End Year    Joined On    School
Student-1       2000         2004        01-Jan     School-ABC
Student-2       2000         2004        03-Jan     School-DEF
Student-3       2000         2004        02-Jan     School-GHI
Student-4       2000         2004        15-Jan     School-DEF
```

Logic behind generating the data:

1. First table contains the list of schools and the seats available (along with the priority in which seats will be allocated to students on [FCFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-come,_first-served) basis)
2. The second table contains data on the list of students enrolled to schools, with their admission date and the start/end year of course.
3. I am required to populate based on the "Fill Order", the school that is allocated to each student.

After analyzing the problem for a while, I have come to a conclusion that, this might not be achievable using select queries alone. Currently, I am planning to do it using two Cursors for each table and process the records row-by-row. Is there a better way of doing it or is it possible through select statements? TIA

**Note:**

- The database I use is Oracle 10g
- I cannot create any temporary tables or alter the data in any of the tables. I strictly have read-only access to the database.

Comment: In your input, student 3 has joined on Jan 15th.  In your output, he has joined on Jan 2nd.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Oracle analytic functions.  `row_number() over ()` can assign a number to each student based on their join date.  `sum() over ()` can calculate the first and last student for each school.  Combining the two you get:

```
select  stud.name
,       stud.startyear
,       stud.endyear
,       stud.joinedon
,       schl.name as SchoolName
from    (
        select  name
        ,       coalesce(sum(NoOfStudents) over (order by FillOrder
                    range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0)+1 FirstStudent
        ,       sum(NoOfStudents) over (order by FillOrder) as LastStudent
        from    Schools
        ) schl
join    (
        select  row_number() over (order by JoinedOn) as StudentRank
        ,       Students.*
        from    Students
        ) stud
on      stud.StudentRank between schl.FirstStudent and schl.LastStudent
order by
        stud.name
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3dc02/13/0)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've never used Analytic functions before, and until I saw your reply I was thinking may be what I wanted was not possible with simple select statements. 
`Actually, the input data and expected output were a little different (somehow I missed to include them in the original question, when I initially posted). I have created a SQL Fiddle and solved it. Am I doing it right, or is there a better way to do it?` [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/305c6/42)  
I am more concerned about the performance of my solution, when the data set is huge!